# Hash function for specific set of Integers

Tags: java, arrays, hash

I have a specific set of Integers which are: 2, 10, 13, 15, 23, 34, 43, 58, 100, 123, 199, 200 and 348. The task is to create a 1 line hash function that could at least map 9 values in the indexes 0 to 12.

So far the hash functions I've made are:

1. `hash = value%13`
2. `hash = (value+array[indexOfValue])%13`
3. `hash = array[indexOfValue]`

Number 3 is something that might get me scold at but it seems acceptable to me so I might as well give it as an answer. Oh and I'm not supposed to use any collision resolution method.

EDIT: So any suggestions on what hash function should I make?

EDIT: I found a function that would map all the values from 0 to 12 and it's :`((((x*7)+x)%7)+x)%13`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @m_callens sorry for that, I've edited it now.

Comment: Voting to close due to requirement of opinionated answers.

Comment: Interesting, single line hash function requirement eliminates the double hashing option. Perhaps a skillfully picked large prime number would work for the hash?

Comment: @MichaelShopsin The number does not need to be prime, or particularly large, because any number above 348 gives you a perfect hash ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: This is not exactly a programming question, it's more like a math puzzle. [so] is for programming questions. This also has infinitely many solutions, so it's probably too broad.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight As per the question, the numbers need to be mapped to [0,12].

Comment: @Dukeling I understand. Michael suggested using a "skillfully picked large prime number," so my reply was to that comment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Good point that 348 is the smallest number guaranteed to work, and that primes are not important. This seems like a great homework question because it focuses on thinking about code and algorithms rather than debugging or coding mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My (educated) guess is that XOR would be a good basis for a hash function here. For example:

```
(value ^ c) % 13
```

By trying all values (brute-force) of c in [1, 200] in the above formula and counting how many distinct hash codes are produced for the values in your set, the number `72` came up. E.g.

```
int[] values = new int[]{2, 10, 13, 15, 23, 34, 43, 58, 100, 123, 199, 200, 348};
for (int value : values) {
    System.out.print((value ^ 72) % 13);
}
```

will print out:

```
9 1 4 6 4 2 8 10 5 12 0 11 3
```

that includes all numbers in the range [0, 12] except 7 and with 4 appearing twice.

Comment: There are 13 elements for 13 possible values, so repetition is not inevitable.

Comment: If somehow you're still curious about a function that maps all values, I found one: hash = ((((x*7)+x)%7)+x)%13